# LibGDX smart collision detection actors

Tags: libgdx, collision

So I'm creating a Towerdefence-game where a lot(5-25) towers will exist.

Now I'm trying to think of a smart way to handle collision detection, meaning that a spawning creature is in range.

The obvious way (for me at least) would be to create a list of creatures and a list of towers, where every tower checks, if a creature is in reach.

But I'm pretty certain that with 20 towers the game would crash soon (especially on a smartphone), since the tower would do those collision-checks EVERY FRAME.

Isn't there some kind of way, where the tower WAITS for a collision, and if it happens, reacts on it? (like a listener, just for collisions)

Comment: I think you are under-estimating hardware these days. If you assume 25 Towers and 50 enemies and 60FPS, that's 75.000 range checks per second. That's pretty much nothing.

Comment: If you check for rectangle collision you will probably don't have any problem..you can try to use Box2d if you are not sure about thoose arrays..